# Ember Data load models from different paths

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a backend with routes:

```ruby
resources :movies do
  collection do
    get :drafts
  end
end
```

store.find('movie') will load from /movies, but I want to load from /movies/drafts.

There is 'suffix' option for finders, thus I realized that I need to write custom finder.
Could anyone post an example?

I tried this code:

```js
App.Movie.reopenClass(  {
  findDrafts: function(store) {
    $.getJSON('/movies/drafts', function(payload) {
      store.pushPayload('movie', payload);
    });

    return store.all('movie');
  }
})
```

But #pushPayload never returns an array of models, thus I use store.all, but it returns all objects in a store. I need just retrieved models by custom ajax request.

There is also store.pushMany that returns an array of models, but it expects normalized payload. What is a proper way to normalize json before passing it to pushMany?

I can't just replace buildURL in adapter, because I want to use default urls too.

**UPDATE:**

Possible solution:

```js
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,

  findAllByUrl: function(type, url) {
    var self = this;
    var promise = Ember.Deferred.create();

    $.getJSON(url, function(payload) {
      var serializer = self.serializerFor(type);
      payload = serializer.extractArray(self, self.modelFor(type), payload);
      var objects = self.pushMany(type, payload);
      promise.resolve(objects);
    });

    return promise;
  }
});

var records = this.get('store').findAllByUrl('movie', '/movies/drafts');
```

It seems to verbose for such simple use case. Any ideas, improvements? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If possible you should really look at moving to Ember Data 1.0 beta.  Things have changed quite a lot.

In the latest version you can override the `pathForType` function in your `Adapter`.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#underscored-api-endpoints

That `TRANSITION` document is very helpful for making the update.

Comment: I am on the edge. I can't override `pathForType` because I also want to load from `/movies`. And also from other collection actions like `movies/top_rated` or `movies/most_viewed`.